SetControlRotation doesn't work for some reason with Unreal engine
My code:
APlayerController* controller = UGameplayStatics::GetPlayerController(this->GetWorld(), 0);
FRotator Rotation = Controller->GetControlRotation();
Controller->SetControlRotation(Rotation.Pitch + amount*5, Rotation.Yaw, Rotation.Roll);

The error I get:
error C2660, function doesnt accept 3 arguments

What is the reason for that ?

It doesn't work because that reason mentioned. Do you have any reasoning, why it should work though?

You need to pass it one FRotator argument, not 3 separate ones for pitch yaw and roll.

it is like X, Y, Z , it should accept it.

Rotation = Yaw, Pitch, Roll

You can try: Controller->SetControlRotation(FRotator(Rotation.Pitch + amount*5, Rotation.Yaw, Rotation.Roll)); - it will aggregate the 3 into 1 FRotator object.

Even if FRotator  is composed of the 3, it is not the same thing.

The problem:
SetControlRotation API requires 1 argument of type FRotator, not 3 separate ones for the rotation components (pitch, yaw, roll).
This is the meaning of the error you get (error C2660, function doesnt accept 3 arguments).
You can fix it in one of the following ways:

Add a FRotator variable created from the 3 components and use it with the API:
FRotator rot = FRotator(Rotation.Pitch + amount*5, 
                        Rotation.Yaw, 
                        Rotation.Roll);
Controller->SetControlRotation(rot);



or:

Construct a FRotator object from the 3 components directly in the API call, like this:
Controller->SetControlRotation(
//--------------------vvvvvvvv--------------------------
                      FRotator(Rotation.Pitch + amount*5, 
                               Rotation.Yaw, 
                               Rotation.Roll));



Note that although FRotator is composed of the 3 components, it is not the same (from the C++ point of view) as the 3 components given separatly.
